# Prevent camera permission to show in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, camera

I'm using [Permission Scope](https://github.com/nickoneill/PermissionScope) to handle permissions to access the camera and the Photolibrary on my app. This is a camera app pretty much like Apple's app.

In my app I call Permission Scope in the first login and it works, but before I touch any button, the "MyApp wants to access the camera" dialog shows. It just happens with the camera dialog, not with the Photo's.

Comment: When you try to access the resource, it may ask the user permission, check if look for valid permissions BEFORE try to access.

Comment: Ok, thanks i will try to make a new view just to ask for permissions since the camera needs to be called immediately